# Does any one know a closed form for $1+\sum \limits_{s=1}^{d} \frac{x^s}{1-x^s}$?

Tags: combinatorics

Does any one know a closed form for $1+\sum \limits_{s=1}^{d} \frac{x^s}{1-x^s}$?

To me, it is the generating function $f(x)=\sum f_n x^n$, where $f_n$ counts the number of composition of $n$ that uses only one type of part.

As an example, $6$, $33$, $222$, $111111$ are the compositions of $6$ which uses only one type of part.

Comment: for $x < 1$ : $\frac{x^s}{1-x^s} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{sk}$ and $$\sum_{s=1}^S \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{sk} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \sum_{d| n} 1_{ d \le S} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \sigma_S(n)x^n$$ where $\sigma_S(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ which are $\le S$

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately there is a pretty obvious bijection (well, an obvious pair of bijections; not so obvious which to prefer) between divisors and compositions using only one type of part.

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks! I should have figured out that.

Comment: @EricStucky : so what ? for defining $\sigma_S(n)$ there isn't really any simpler way  than $\sum_{d | n} 1_{d \le S}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this will be helping you very much.

$$\sum \limits_{s=1}^{d} \frac{x^s}{1-x^s}=\frac{\psi _x(1)-\psi _x(d+1)}{\log (x)}$$ where appears the [q-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).